# $10\log_{10}(X)$ or $20\log_{10}(X)$ dB values - how to tell?

Tags: analysis, measurement, db

Inspired by [this question](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/q/337/131) on dBs, I wanted to ask about a potentially dumb confusion I always have.

When referring to an absolute measurement value, dBs always come with a reference. However, it is not always clear to me which one is being referred to. Sometimes, $10log_{10}$ is used, and sometimes $20log_{10}$ is used to report dB values. Papers typically don't explicitly state which dB they are reporting (I myself somehow too haven't done so in the past!).

I often end up guessing whether 10 or 20 is being used as the 'prefix' for the dB calculation, based on what I know from previous studies. This guessing however fails of course when I'm reading papers from a new field.

Are there any rules of thumb that can be used to decide if the authors mean $10log_{10}$ or $20log_{10}$? when reporting their measurement values?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

**In practice, it shouldn't matter whether you are using $10\log_{10}($power_ratio$)$ or $20\log_{10}($pressure_ratio$)$ to report your results - they should give the same value in dB, as long as you are using them correctly:**

- [**when comparing powers/energies, use the $10\log_{10}$ formula**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel#Power_quantities);
- [**when comparing pressures/voltages, use the $20\log_{10}$ formula**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel#Root-power_(field)_quantities).

---

**Long explanation:**

Originally, decibels were used to describe a ratio of *powers* (in fact, [the loss of electrical power in signals sent across telephone/telegraph wires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel#History)), and the definition of the decibel is the $10\log_{10}(W_{value}/W_{ref})$ formula, where $W$ denotes power.

However, electrical power in Watts is relatively difficult to measure, so it's convenient to infer its value from other, easier-to-measure quantities, such as voltages or currents. These can be related using the expressions $W = V\cdot I = V^2/R = R\cdot I^2$ where $V$ is the voltage, $I$ is the current, and $R$ is the resistance/impedance. In this context, voltage and current can be called "[root-power quantities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power,_root-power,_and_field_quantities)", as their value depends on the square-root of the power.

From that, making a few minor assumptions (linearity, constant resistance/impedance, and a few other minor details), *one can obtain the same value for the ratio of *powers* in decibels from the ratio of voltages squared* as $10\log_{10}(V_{value}^2 / V_{ref}^2)$. Using logarithm rules, this can be simplified to  $20\log_{10}(V_{value}/ V_{ref})$, which is a ratio of voltages (not squared). Now, **one can obtain the same value in decibels either from the ratio of *powers* using  $10\log_{10}$ or from the ratio of *voltages* using $20\log_{10}$**.

In acoustics, the same principle applies: acoustic pressure $p$ in Pascals is the "root-power" quantity for acoustic power $W$ - i.e. acoustic power $W$ is proportional to acoustic pressure squared $p^2$, although the actual expression depends on the propagation conditions (plane/spherical wave, air/water, etc). Therefore, one can obtain the same value in decibels from either $10\log_{10}(W_{value} / W_{ref})$  or $20\log_{10}(p_{value} / p_{ref})$ .

Answer (score 7):

The $10\log_{10}()$ refers to a measure for acoustic energy. This should be used when adding up different sources, because you may add acoustic energy and not acoustic amplitude. Energy is related to the square of the amplitude.
$20\log_{10}()$ shoudl be used for amplitude.

Answer (score 7):

All the answers made so far are correct.

I only would like to add that the word deciBel has 'deci' in the word so that deciBel means 1 tenth of a Bel. As @fabi_hirono indicates deciBel was created for power ratios, so 10 log(Power/Power_ref) is always correct.

For sound waves, the use 20 log(Pressure/Pressure_ref) is only correct in the far field. Btw, I would not call the far field assumption, or real impedance assumption, a 'minor' assumption, but a realistic one, if measurements are far away from point source.

Comment: I thought the `20*log10(p/p_ref)` form was also valid for spherical waves? I know it is often used withouth making a plane wave assumption, at least in air. In Pierce - Acoustics (3rd Ed), Sec. 2.3.5, he says the Sound Intensity Level `10*log10(I/I_ref)` and Sound Pressure Level `20*log10(p/p_ref)` are approximately the same for plane AND spherical waves in air, at least. Did I miss something?

Comment: You are correct, that is why I had changed to 'far field' (plane-field was a mistake). In the nearfield Impedance get complex, so 20log10(.) does not work

Answer (score 5):

This is the formula to convert an acoustic pressure from Pa to dB:  $20\log_{10}(p_{RMS}/p_{ref})$ where:

- $p_{ref}$ is a reference pressure corresponding to 0dB (e.g. 20µPa for the dB SPL scale)
- $p_{RMS}$ is the root mean square of the pressure over a certain period of time

This formula is equivalent to  $10\log_{10}(p_{RMS}^2/p_{ref}^2)$ which is sometimes used when talking about sound power or sound intensity because these quantities are related to pressures squared.

Comment: The most commonly used reference pressure for media other than gases is 1µPa. See ASA [reference value for sound pressure](https://asastandards.org/terms/reference-value-for-sound-pressure-2/).